# Proof of Fourier transform of cos$2\pi ft$

Tags: proof-explanation, fourier-transform

Hi im looking for the worked example proof for the fourier transform of cos $2\pi ft$ , using the fourier transform equation in the form $$G(f)=\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} g(t)e^{-j2\pi ft}$$

Comment: Have you tried anything? If so, where did you get stuck?

Comment: The function $\cos(t)$ is not integrable, so its Fourier transform is _not_ defined by that equation! It's a tempered distribution; it has a Fourier transform "in the sense of that distributions", but the definition of the Fourier transform of a distribution is not that integral.

Comment: Hello John, actually i can do this proof with the $w$ form and wanted someone to check my work using the general form. Its part of a larger question which is asking me to use the Inverse Fourier Transform mathematical expression to work backwards to some multiple of cos2$\pi fct$(we aren't given that, but its easy to deduce) however we are only taught the fourier of transform of $w$ to $t$ and vice versa, not of f.
For reference, https://imgur.com/a/kbGyP

Comment: Hello David, if thats the case, then im a bit lost, because an entire third of my module is therefore based on integrals that are not integrable hahaha.
Jokes aside, In our module, the transform and its inverse are used as tools to help solve differential equations in the frequency domain, which is much easier than in the time domain.